# Comparing TextBox Text value to integers doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, variables, textbox, comparison

Let me set the scene:
I am creating a times table practice quiz for a school and need to compare a variable to the value of `TextBox1.Text`. The variable is of type `Integer`

Here is my code:

```
    Dim answer As Integer = (num1 * num2)

    If TextBox1.Text = answer.ToString Then
        question()
    Else
        Dim typedAnswer As String = TextBox1.Text
        timeCheck.Stop()
        MsgBox("Sorry, " & typedAnswer & " is not the correct answer. Please try again.")
        timeCheck.Start()
    End If
```

To clarify:

`question` is a sub I have created

`answer` is the answer to the question as an `Integer`

`num1` is one of the numbers that is being multiplied

`num2` is the other number that is being multiplied

Whenever I press the button that triggers this code, it just activates the code that means the answer is incorrect, even though it is. For example: I get the question `9 multiplied by 5`. I would then type 45, but the code would activate the bottom part of the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: What the type of num1 and num2 ?

Comment: @Muhammad They are integers

Comment: I have tried your code and it works for me as is, I believe that the problem is related to something else you didn't post here.

Comment: Can you print num1, num2 and typedAnswer and post it here?

Comment: I found the reason. I was calling `num1` and `num2` each time, and their variable's values was `rnd.Next(1, 12)`, with `rnd` equalling `New Random` which meant it generated new numbers each time! Sorry about that - Rookie Mistake :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. I was calling `num1` and `num2` each time, and their values were `rnd.Next(1, 12)`, with `rnd` equalling `New Random()` which meant it generated new numbers each time! Sorry about that! Rookie Mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing Like

```
If val(TextBox1.Text) = answer Then
        question()
    Else
        Dim typedAnswer As String = TextBox1.Text
        timeCheck.Stop()
        MsgBox("Sorry, " & typedAnswer & " is not the correct answer. Please try again.")
        timeCheck.Start()
    End If
```

Using number values as string is not good practice.hope it helps.

Comment: Still exactly the same.

Comment: is the Value of `answer` the same as the text u enter?? Put Breakpoint and check.

Comment: both `val(textbox1.text)` and `answer` are equal?

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help you:

```
If CInt(TextBox1.Text) = answer Then
    ...
End If
```

That should work fine.